# I'm a beginner and I'm having trouble with the home page of a web app. I've started a 'so-called' prototype purely in html

Tags: javascript, html

The page is supposed to display a window block depending on the checked category in the sidebar. But it displays all the blocks at once regardless of what is checked. I'm not sure if I made a mistake in the js function or is it the html file.

```js
function showContent() {
    s = document.getElementById('skills');
    i = document.getElementById('interests');
    e = document.getElementById('education');
    id1 = document.getElementById('cont1');
    id2 = document.getElementById('cont2');
    id3 = document.getElementById('cont3');

    if (s.is(":checked"))
    {
        id1.show();
        id2.hide();
        id3.hide();
    }else if (i.is(":checked")) {
        id1.hide();
        id2.show();
        id3.hide();
    } else if (i.is(":checked")) {
        id1.hide();
        id2.hide();
        id3.show();
    }else {
        id1.hide();
        id2.hide();
        id3.hide();
    }
};
```

```css
*{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-image: url(../Prof_slike/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: aliceblue;
    margin-top: 0%;
}

.wrap h2{
    color:aliceblue;
}

.formbox{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black, dimgray, darkgray);
    text-align: left;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 128px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255);
}

.formbox header{
    color:white;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.input label{
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
}

.input input{
    width:100%;
}

.submit input{
    background-color:darkorchid;
    width:100%;
}

.submit input:hover{
    color:white;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.links a:hover{
    color:blueviolet;
}

.nav{
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, black, dimgray, darkgray);
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.nav a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav input[type=text]{
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.nav a:hover{
    color:white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.nav a.active{
    opacity: 0.5;
    color:black;
}

.btn{
    float:right;
    color:white;
    background-color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .btn, .nav input[type=text] {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 14px;
    }
}

.content{
    display:table;
}

.sidenav {
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 1;
    background:linear-gradient(to right, black, dimgray, darkgray);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.box{
    float: right;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url(../Prof_slike/image3.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.box h3{
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding:2px 2px;
}

.card{
    position:relative;
    width: 970px;
    height: 340px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: initial;
}

.card p{
    color:black;
    font-size: 12px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    .box, .card, .sidenav {width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Skill exchange</h2>
        <div class="nav">
            <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="edit.html">Change profile</a>
            <a href="logout.html">Log out</a>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..."><button class="btn">Search</button>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="sidenav">
                Skills<input type="radio" id="skills" name="choice" class="skill" onclick="showContent()" checked><br>
                Interests<input type="radio" id="interests" name="choice" class="interest" onclick="showContent()"><br>
                Education<input type="radio" id="education" name="choice" class="education" onclick="showContent()"><br>
            </div>
            <div class="box" id="cont1">
                <h3>Skills</h3>
                <div class="card" contenteditable="true">
                    <p>My skills are...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box" id="cont2">
                <h3>Interests</h3>
                <div class="card" contenteditable="true">
                    <p>My interests are...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box" id="cont3">
                <h3>Education</h3>
                <div class="card" contenteditable="true">
                    <p>My education is...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="constructors.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result is this. It should display one window block at a time.

[image: The result]

Comment: it would be helpful if your code was in text form so it could be copied and tested.

Comment: I tried to put it in text form but it sent me an error saying it wasn't properly converted.

Comment: How to use snippets https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Found it. Sorry, it's my first time here.

Comment: HTML elements do not (AFAIK) have an `is` method, you should be seeing a Javascript error in your browser console. You also aren't showing us any place where you are actually *calling* your function.

Comment: You're trying to use jQuery methods `.is()`, `.show()`, and `.hide()` on vanilla DOM elements.

Comment: Ah, I see. Looks like I mixed up. Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of things to fix here. First add jquery then use  `$("#cont1").show();` and if you want to show only one element on page load then set other elements to hide

example code:

```js
      class Administrator {
        constructor(username, email, age, password) {
          this.username = username;
          this.email = email;
          this.age = age;
          this.password = password;
        }
      }

      class User {
        constructor(username, email, password) {
          this.username = username;
          this.email = email;
          this.age = age;
          this.password = password;
        }
      }
      $("#cont1").show();
      $("#cont2").hide();
      $("#cont3").hide();
      function showContent() {
        s = document.getElementById("skills");
        i = document.getElementById("interests");
        e = document.getElementById("education");
        id1 = document.getElementById("cont1");
        id2 = document.getElementById("cont2");
        id3 = document.getElementById("cont3");

        if (s.checked) {
          $("#cont1").show();
          $("#cont2").hide();
          $("#cont3").hide();
        } else if (i.checked) {
          $("#cont1").hide();
          $("#cont2").show();
          $("#cont3").hide();
        } else if (e.checked) {
          $("#cont1").hide();
          $("#cont2").hide();
          $("#cont3").show();
        } else {
          $("#cont1").hide();
          $("#cont2").hide();
          $("#cont3").hide();
        }
      }
```

```css
* {
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }

      body {
        background-image: url(../Prof_slike/background.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: aliceblue;
        margin-top: 0%;
      }

      .wrap h2 {
        color: aliceblue;
      }

      .formbox {
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black, dimgray, darkgray);
        text-align: left;
        width: 400px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 0 0 128px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255);
      }

      .formbox header {
        color: white;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      }

      .input label {
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
      }

      .input input {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .submit input {
        background-color: darkorchid;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .submit input:hover {
        color: white;
        background-color: blueviolet;
        opacity: 0.7;
      }

      .links a:hover {
        color: blueviolet;
      }

      .nav {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, dimgray, darkgray);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }

      .nav a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .nav input[type="text"] {
        float: right;
        width: 400px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: none;
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      .nav a:hover {
        color: white;
        opacity: 0.7;
        background-color: blueviolet;
      }

      .nav a.active {
        opacity: 0.5;
        color: black;
      }

      .btn {
        float: right;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .btn,
        .nav input[type="text"] {
          float: none;
          display: block;
          text-align: left;
          width: fit-content;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 14px;
        }
      }

      .content {
        display: table;
      }

      .sidenav {
        float: left;
        position: fixed;
        height: 300px;
        z-index: 1;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, black, dimgray, darkgray);
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-top: 10px;
        text-align: right;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }

      .box {
        float: right;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 400px;
        background-image: url(../Prof_slike/image3.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 100px;
      }

      .box h3 {
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 2px 2px;
      }

      .card {
        position: relative;
        width: 970px;
        height: 340px;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-align: initial;
      }

      .card p {
        color: black;
        font-size: 12px;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
        .box,
        .card,
        .sidenav {
          width: fit-content;
        }
      }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h2>Skill exchange</h2>
    <div class="nav">
      <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="edit.html">Change profile</a>
      <a href="logout.html">Log out</a>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." /><button class="btn">Search</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="sidenav">
        Skills<input type="radio" id="skills" name="choice" class="skill" onclick="showContent()" checked /><br />
        Interests<input type="radio" id="interests" name="choice" class="interest" onclick="showContent()" /><br />
        Education<input type="radio" id="education" name="choice" class="education" onclick="showContent()" /><br />
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="cont1">
        <h3>Skills</h3>
        <div class="card" contenteditable="true">
          <p>My skills are...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="cont2">
        <h3>Interests</h3>
        <div class="card" contenteditable="true">
          <p>My interests are...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="cont3">
        <h3>Education</h3>
        <div class="card" contenteditable="true">
          <p>My education is...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried something similar earlier, but jQuery isn't my strong suit. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: In that case use document.getElementById("cont1").style.visibility = "hidden"; and document.getElementById("cont1").style.visibility = "visible"; In your code is id1.style.visibility = "hidden";

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code so it only show-cases your problem.

- Never use float unless you know what you're doing.
- Never assign width or height to an element unless you know what
  you're doing. Use max-width and max-height instead.
- Always use `const` or `let` to declare variables.
- Use the correct semantic for the tags.
- Use understandable variable names and classes that actually describes what they are used for.
- Use loops when you have several elements that needs to change.

I used a CSS variable to control the spacing on all elements.

I added a label and inputs that uses the same name so they are all connected.

I added event listeners to all inputs that listens to the 'change' event.

I renamed the box ids to match the input ids so it's easier to use the input id and add `-info` to find the id for the corresponding `.box`.

You can use the hidden attribute that almost all elements have. Hide all elements, then show the element that you want to display.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav input').forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', showContent);
})

function showContent({target}) {
  document.querySelectorAll('section > .box').forEach(infoBox => {
    infoBox.hidden = true;
  })
  
  const boxToDisplay = document.getElementById(target.id + '-info');
  
  if (boxToDisplay) {
     boxToDisplay.hidden = false;
  }
};

showContent({target: document.querySelector('.sidenav input[checked]')})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --spacing: 1rem;
  --spacing-quarter: 0.25rem;
}

html, body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: var(--spacing);
  background: darkblue;
}

input, label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

.links a:hover {
  color: blueviolet;
}

main {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.sidenav {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black, dimgray, darkgray);
  padding: var(--spacing);
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.sidenav > div {
  padding: var(--spacing-quarter) 0px;
}

.box {
  background-image: url(../Prof_slike/image3.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

.box h3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.card {
  min-height: 340px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: initial;
}

.card p {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="sidenav">
    <div>
      <label for="skills">Skills</label>
      <input type="radio" name="navselector" checked id="skills" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="interests">Interests</label>
      <input type="radio" name="navselector" id="interests" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="education">Education</label>
      <input type="radio" name="navselector" id="education" />
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <section>
    <div class="box" id="skills-info">
      <h3>Skills</h3>
      <div class="card" contenteditable="true">
        <p>My skills are...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box" id="interests-info">
      <h3>Interests</h3>
      <div class="card" contenteditable="true">
        <p>My interests are...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box" id="education-info">
      <h3>Education</h3>
      <div class="card" contenteditable="true">
        <p>My education is...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</main>
```